# Ruby GPGME - How to encrypt large files

Tags: ruby, encryption, gpgme

I'm having difficulty to Encrypt large files (bigger than available memory) using GPGME in Ruby.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'gpgme'

def gpgfile(localfile)
  crypto = GPGME::Crypto.new
  filebasename = File.basename(localfile)
  filecripted = crypto.encrypt File.read(localfile), :recipients => "info@address.com", :always_trust => true
  File.open("#{localfile}.gpg", 'w') { |file| file.write(filecripted) }
end

gpgpfile("/home/largefile.data")
```

In this case I got an error of memory allocation: 
*"read: failed to allocate memory (NoMemoryError)"*

Someone can explain me how to read the source file chunk by chunk (of 100Mb for example) and write them passing by the crypting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious problem is that you're reading the entire file into memory with `File.read(localfile)`. The [`Crypto#encrypt`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/ueno/ruby-gpgme/GPGME/Crypto#encrypt-instance_method) method will take an IO object as its input, so instead of `File.read(localfile)` (which returns the contents of the file as a string) you can pass it a File object. Likewise, you can give an IO object as the `:output` option, letting you write the output directly to a file instead of in memory:

```
def gpgfile(localfile)
  infile = File.open(localfile, 'r')
  outfile = File.open("#{localfile}.gpg", 'w')

  crypto = GPGME::Crypto.new    
  crypto.encrypt(infile, recipients: "info@address.com",
                         output: outfile,
                         always_trust: true)
ensure
  infile.close
  outfile.close
end
```

I've never used ruby-gpgme, so I'm not 100% sure this will solve your problem since it depends a bit on what ruby-gpgme does behind the scenes, but from the docs and the source I've peeked at it seems like a sanely-built gem so I'm guessing this will do the trick.

Comment: I just use gpgme and this is how I do it so it should work (although I use the block form of File.open)

Comment: Dear downvoter: Please leave a comment explaining the reason for your downvote. If my answer is lacking I would appreciate the opportunity to improve it.

Comment: Just tested for my purposes and it works like a charm, thanks a lot!